# How to eliminate hardcoding when switch case like conditions are used by function to be called

Tags: java, software-design

Consider a common validation function.

```
private static void check(int[][] m1, int[][] m2, char op) {
    if (m1 == null || m2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("No input matrix should be null.");
    }
    /**
     * Switch case was thought to be beneficial in case of future extensibility.
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Advantages_and_disadvantages
     */
    switch (op) {
        case 'a' : if (m1.length != m2.length && m1[0].length != m2[0].length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla"); else break;
        case 'm' : if (m1[0].length != m2.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla"); else break;
    }
}
```

Here if 'a' is passed then validation ensures matrices are good for multiplication, if m is passed its good for addition. However, I can see several loopholes in this code, eg: 1. the client needs to be aware of what to pass as parameter 2. Client may pass in a wrong character. A global constants or enums are my possible solutions.. Is there a better / more common method to solve this problem ? Thanks,

Comment: Your check for addition is incorrect.  Should use '||' instead of '&&'.

Comment: You also don't need the `else` statements since it will either `throw` or `break`.

Answer (score 3):

Enums will be much better than global constants because with a global constant it's still easy pass in a bad value. I'm assuming your values would be `int`s, so the user could pass in any `int`. Enums will do typechecking for you, so that's a plus.

However, why don't you just refactor this into 2 different methods: `checkMult` vs `checkAdd`? These are doing totally different checks, so there's no reason (as far as I can see) they shouldn't be different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write one method to check two entirely different things. This should be two methods, one  for multiplication and one for addition.